# How do I Stop Changes in Excel 365 showing before they are approved by using Track Changes

Tags: excel, office365, ms-office

I'm working with Excel in Office 365 and I have a speadsheet that I would like everyone in my organisation to be able to edit. However, I don't want the spreadsheed to show everyone the changes - As the administrator, I would like to carefully control what is displayed to everyone.

The spreadsheet is essentially a feedback form where Students can type questions and then Instructors can provide a response. However, rather than just allowing the answers to questions to be posted immediately, I would like to have the ability to moderate the answers before posting to avoid a period where a potentially incorrect or misleading answer is provided. i.e. the 'answer' box remains blank until the input has been Accepted as a change.

I can't find how to do this using Track Changes.

What I have at the moment is a Form using MS Forms that the students can use to populate the Student Questions part then instructors can access the spreadsheet to provide answers. The students have read only/view access of the spreadsheet.

I appreciate that excel isn't the best solution for this kind of thing however, I am limited to using MS Excel 365 by my organisation, I can't use VBA or Macros either so am limited to core Excel functionality.

Thanks in advnace for any suggestions.

I have tried using Track Changes but can't find the functionality that I require.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.